# ¿Cómo recuperar valores de un array para comparación?

Tags: php, array

La función de este código es (o debería ser) obtener fechas desde una base de datos, para luego compararlas con la fecha actual y alertar si se cumple el plazo de tiempo de un año, por el momento no tengo problemas con la parte de comparación de fechas.

El problema viene aquí: las fechas las obtengo desde la BD con un `do...while` y las almaceno en un array llamado "datos[]", el problema es que si quiero obtener una fecha especifica del arreglo de la forma típica, por ejemplo:

```
echo $datos[3];
```

Esto me devuelve al valor "array" y no la fecha que esta en la posición numero 3, esto lo solucioné recorriendo el arreglo con un "foreach" con lo cual si me muestra la fecha que esta en la posición numero 3(por ejemplo), pero fuera del "foreach" me sigue arrojando "array" y no la fecha.

Pero hay otro problema y es que el `foreach` se repite según los datos que haya en el arreglo, por lo tanto la parte de la comparación de fechas se repite más veces de las necesarias. Espero entiendan que no tengo problemas con la parte de comparación de fechas, **el problema principal es la obtención de los datos dentro del array**.

Éste es mi código:

```
<?php require_once('../../../Connections/conex_banana.php'); ?>

<?php
session_start();
$id_cliente=$_SESSION['MM_Username'];
mysql_select_db($database_conex_banana, $conex_banana);
$alerta_query=sprintf("SELECT fecha_ate FROM atencion_adr WHERE id_cliente=$id_cliente");
$alerta = mysql_query($alerta_query, $conex_banana) or die(mysql_error());

 if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($alerta))
    {
        $datos = array();
        do {
             $puen = $row['fecha_ate'];
             $datos[] = array($puen);
             }
             while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($alerta));

    $longitud = count($datos);
    echo $longitud;                       //esto solo lo hago para comprobar en 
    echo "<br />";                        //pantalla que el array
                                          //viene con "fechas"


        foreach ($datos as  $value)
        {

            for($i=0; $i<$longitud; $i++)       //esto solo lo hago para 
                                                //saber que valores(fechas) trae
            echo $value[$i];                        
            echo "<br />";

//  Aquí "creo" que esta el problema, como este for esta dentro del foreach
// que se repite cuantas veces datos haya, el proceso que se supone que 
//se tiene que hacer una vez, se repite según valores traiga "$datos",
// y la idea es que la comparación de fechas solo se realice 1 vez por dato.
//Además solo conozco la opción foreach para obtener los datos del arreglo, ya //que si pongo el código fuera 
// del foreach por ejemplo: "echo $datos[0];" esto me arroja el valor "Array", //pero si lo hago dentro del 
// foreach por ejemplo: "echo value[0];" esto me arroja el resultado 2017-05-10 que sería lo correcto(ejemplo).


            for($i=0; $i<$longitud; $i++)
            {
                $fecha_db = $value[$i];
                $timeActual= time();
                $ahora=strtotime($timeActual);
                $fecha_atencion= strtotime($fecha_db);
                $segundos_year = 365 * 24* 60* 60;

                if($fecha_atencion-$ahora >= $segundos_year)

                            { ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                            alert("La atención esta caducada");
                        </script>
                <?php }else { ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                            alert("no hay atenciones próximas a caducar");
                        </script>
                <?php }
                 }
               }
    }else
    {
        echo "¡ No se ha encontrado fechas próximas !";
    }
?>
```

Comment: No será que te devuelve un objecto DateTime (y por lo tanto es un array)? Prueba a hacer: $puen->format('Y-m-d);

Comment: Prueba a cambiar `$datos[] = array($puen);` por `array_push($datos, $puen);`. Estas metiendo en `$datos` otro array con `$puen` dentro, quedando asi: `datos = [ [ $puen ] ]`. Por eso te imprime `Array`. Aparte, tambien te funcionaria cambiando `echo $value[$i];` por `echo $value[$i][0];`, pero mi primera solucion es la correcta ya que estructuras el array como realmente quieres.